# Embedding an Image in a Tkinter Canvas widget using PIL

Tags: python, image, embed, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to embed an image in a Tkinter canvas using PIL, and for some reason it's not displaying. Any Ideas?

There are no errors or warnings. Just a blank Tk window.

My code:

```
import Tkinter
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class image_manip(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)

        self.ImbImage = Tkinter.Canvas(self)
        self.ImbImage.pack()

        i = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('test.png'))
        self.ImbImage.create_image(0, 0, image=i)

def run():
    image_manip(None).mainloop()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that the image is getting garbage-collected. Try saving a reference to "i" (eg: self.image=i)

Comment: @Bryan Oakley That was my exact problem as well. How did you know? Why would an image be garbage-collected so promptly, even if there is a reference to it on the next line? What difference does that `self.` make?

Comment: @theJollySin: the difference `self` makes is that without it, `i` is a local variable. When that function ends, `i` could be garbage-collected. With `self`, the reference exists for the life of the object.

Comment: @BryanOakley: It is surprising this works, because that means that the `ImbImage.create_image()` call does *not* create a reference to the image. That is unexpected, I guess.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: you are correct: `ImbImage.create_image()` does not create a reference to the image object. It's simply telling the underlying tcl/tk interpreter to place the image on a canvas. The tcl/tk interpreter and canvas has no knowledge of python objects.